# JVM disable inlining for a particular class or method

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, inlining

I am trying to write some benchmark just to measure effect of inlining a method. Does anybody know if is it possible to disable inlining for a particular class or method on HostSpot JVM?

I found `-XX:-Inline` which disable inlining in total.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything that will stop java inlining a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886577/is-there-anything-that-will-stop-java-inlining-a-method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `-XX:CompileCommand` JVM option to control just-in-time compilation. The option can be used for excluding certain methods (or all methods of a class) to be compiled, and more. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html):

> Specifies a command to perform on a method. For example, to exclude the `indexOf()` method of the String class from being compiled, use the following:
>
> `-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,java/lang/String.indexOf`

If you only want to prevent method inlining, you can use the `dontinline` command with the same syntax, e.g.

```
-XX:CompileCommand=dontinline,java/lang/String.indexOf
```

The same JVM option is used internally by the popular Java microbenchmark harness, [JMH](http://java-performance.info/jmh/).